# Can't create an Azure web site

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Help! When I try to creat a web site on Azure, I receive the following error message:

There was no endpoint listening at https://geomaster.azurewebsites.windows.net/subscriptions/2762018c-1ace-4b11-a55d-7b69d004cca3/webspaces/eastuswebspace/sites that could accept the message.

I was able to create 2 sites about 3 months ago without any problem. My subscription is an active pay as you go account. I'm not trying to do anything advanced, just a web site connected to a SQL DB. The SQL DB creates without a problem. I was also able to create a virtual Win2008 machine. Azure reps have said my account is fine. I don't know where else to look. Thanks
-ph

Answer (score 0):

If your development machine is behind a proxy server, the problem could be caused by the machine's proxy server settings. Have a look at them via Control Panel / Network and Internet / Internet Options / Connections tab / Lan Settings and try checking the box for 'Automatically detect settings' if it isn't.

[Solved: Azure Problem - There was no endpoint listening at that could accept the message](http://iamdotnetcrazy.blogspot.nl/2012/05/solved-azure-problem-there-was-no.html)

[Windows Azure Package Deployment Failed with Error - "There was no endpoint listening"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/07/08/windows-azure-package-deployment-failed-with-error-quot-there-was-no-endpoint-listening-at-https-management-core-windows-net-quot.aspx)

Comment: The Dev machine is not behind a proxy server. The problem continues.

Answer (score 0):

Same for me. Seems they simply do not have enough recourses atm.
refs:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/611545bc-a061-4107-9240-597b60131b8b/error-creating-azure-website

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/389cba4f-8943-4f56-8b0e-9f9066154337/error-creating-azure-website